# Why I can't access my escaped URL?

Tags: java, android, url, android-asynctask, uri

I'm trying to send some params to my server in `AsyncTask`, but without any luck.

Here is my code:

```
try {
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.dummyurl.com/android/agent.php")
                        .appendQueryParameter("date", selectedDate.getText().toString()+" "+ selectedTime.getText().toString())
                        .appendQueryParameter("user", userTxt.getText().toString())
                        .appendQueryParameter("cal", calTxt.getText().toString());
                String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

                System.out.println(myUrl);

                URL url = new URL(myUrl);

                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

`myUrl` looks like: `https://www.dummyurl.com%2Fandroid%2Fagent.php?date=February-6-2015%2014%3A49&user=qwe&cal=qweqwe`

But I'm getting the following error:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null`

I understand that for some reason I can not connect to the escaped URL, I know that I messed the things up, but as an android beginner, I really can't find a way to make a request to my URL. I know that I'm missing a small part here, but I'm not able to spot it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Uri.Builder.appendPath` to add host name and path to uri as:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
        .authority("www.dummyurl.com")
        .appendPath("android")
        .appendPath("agent.php")
        ....
```